# How to override CSS to change <th> of bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want some of the table headers to be aligned to the center, while the other to the left. I tried vaiours methods to override the the  in bootstrap. But I couldnt succeed. Here are the things I tried out :

I created a class called as `column-center`. The html looks like this :

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Roll#</th>
    <th style="width: 20%">First Name</th>
    <th style="width: 20%">Middle Name</th>
    <th style="width: 20%">Last Name</th>
    <th class="column-center" style="width: 10%">Class</th>
    <th class="column-center" style="width: 10%">Division</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

The CSS I tried are :

```
.column-center > thead > tr > th{
text-align: center !important;
}
.column-center > thead > tr > th, .column-center > tbody > tr > th, .column-center > tfoot > tr > th, .column-center > thead > tr > td, .column-center > tbody > tr > td, .column-center > tfoot > tr > td{
text-align: center !important;
}
.column-center > tr > th{
text-align: center !important;
}
.column-center .table > thead > tr > th{
text-align: center !important;
}
table > thead > tr > th .column-center{
text-align: center !important;
}
table.table.table-striped tr.column-center td{
text-align: center !important;
}
.column-center > thead > tr > th, .column-center > tbody > tr > th, .column-center > tfoot > tr > th, .column-center > thead > tr > td, .column-center > tbody > tr > td, .column-center > tfoot > tr > td{
text-align: center;
}
.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > th.column-center {
text-align: center !important;
}
.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > td.column-center {
text-align: center;
}
.table tbody tr th{
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are including your custom css AFTER bootstrap? Looking at their css a simple `th {text-align: center}` should do it.

Comment: Yes. I am sure because I have used the same css to override another style. If i do th {text-align: center} it will change the entire th property. I want 2 of the headers to be centered. Rest to the left.

Comment: Can you use the developer tools in your browser, click on the th and see where it's getting its styling from?

Comment: Can you see where your CSS is crossed out in the chain of CSS? Or do you not see it at all. hard to know without seeing all of your stuff in action. Rest assured, something must be messed up in how your CSS is loading or something. Try adding a style tag on the page and see if it takes. if it does, then you know it's your files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution for your issue i had added snippet code here,
simply add a class(centre-align) in html and gave style(text-align) in your custom style-sheet.

in head section of the HTML don't forget to add the customised style sheet bellow the bootstrap style sheet

```
<head>
    <link href="../bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="../custom-style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body></body>
```

```css
.center-align{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Condensed Table</h2>
  <table class="table table-condensed">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th class="center-align">Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: The class `.text-center` is native to Bootstrap as an alignment class.  Your solution works, but it is creating a duplicate of an already-existing class.  See: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment

Comment: Yesh off course, But here i am saying about the simple way to override bootstrap style with your custom style,
i just add "centre-align" as a sample class. You can add any style to this class as your need(its not about text-align) it will override the bootstrap style. 
the key thing is you must link the bootstrap and custom style sheet properly.
Thank you,

Comment: Yes. There was a conflict with the class name.            '.center-align{
  text-align:center;
}      '   worked for me. Thank you guys a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Just add the .text-center class to the ones you want to align to the center

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr> 
      <th>#</th> 
      <th class="text-center">First Name</th> 
      <th>Last Name</th> 
      <th>Username</th> 
    </tr> 
  </thead> 
  <tbody> 
    <tr> 
      <th scope="row">1</th> 
      <td>Mark</td> 
      <td>Otto</td> 
      <td>@mdo</td> 
    </tr> 
   <tr> 
     <th scope="row">2</th>
     <td>Jacob</td> 
     <td>Thornton</td> 
     <td>@fat</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
      <th scope="row">3</th> 
      <td>Larry</td> 
      <td>the Bird</td> 
      <td>@twitter</td> 
    </tr> 
  </tbody> 
</table>
```

Comment: This will work. But I wanted to do it in CSS. Got the solution. There was a conflict with the class name.